# Method doesn't run when invoked

Tags: objective-c, macos

EDIT: Problem has been solved, I moved allocation and initiation of variables into another method. `SubOtherClass` never gets initiated (`alloc` and `init` are never called).

Classes have been renamed to make this question more general.
Hypothetical class `OtherClass` extends `NSView`
Hypothetical class `SubOtherClass` extends the hypothetical class `OtherClass` and invokes the update method in a local instance of `ClassToUpdate`
I understand that updating the view when a key gets released is not the best of ideas, but that's only temporary. I'm not an expert in Obj-C. To repeat the problem, the update method in `SubOtherClass` gets executed but not in `ClassToUpdate`, and the content (not shown here) of that method doesn't run. How can I fix this? If anymore info is necessary, just ask.

Thanks.

Edit: Full code (with renamed classes)

Header:

```
#import "OtherClass.h"
#import "ThingToRender.h"
#import "ClassToUpdate.h"

@interface SubOtherClass : OtherClass

@property (assign) ThingToRender *thingToRender1, *thingToRender2;
@property (retain) ClassToUpdate *classToUpdate;

- (void) createVariables;
- (void) update;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "SubOtherClass.h"

@implementation SubOtherClass

- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder{
    return true;
}

- (void) createVariables{
    self.classToUpdate = [[ClassToUpdate alloc] init];
    self.thingToRender1 = [[ThingToRender alloc] init];
    self.thingToRender2 = [[ThingToRender alloc] init];
}

- (void) keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    [super keyUp:theEvent];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:true];
}

- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}

- (void) update{
    [self.classToUpdate update:self];
}

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self update];
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
    [self.color1 set]; //this color is declared in superclass
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d %d %d", self.thingToRender1.x, self.thingToRender1.y, 30, 100];
    NSRectFill(NSRectFromString(str1));
    [self.color2 set]; //this color is declared in superclass
    str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d %d %d", self.thingToRender2.x, self.thingToRender2.y, 30, 100];
    NSRectFill(NSRectFromString(str1));
    [self.color3 set]; //this color is declared in superclass
    str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d %d %d", self.classToUpdate.x, self.classToUpdate.y, 30, 30];
    NSRectFill(NSRectFromString(str1));
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return self;
}

@end
```

OtherClass extends NSView

Comment: Are you sure that `self.classToUpdate` is correctly assigned (i.e. not `nil`)? BTW, the name selectioon is not so good: I guess, it is not a class but an object. In case, your want to call a class, `update` should be a class method (not object method).

Comment: The names are just examples, they aren't the REAL names I used, but I'll try to use better names next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what was causing the problem, and I find it complicated, but I eventually found the solution. I moved constructors for the variables to another method, and `alloc` is never called on `SubOtherClass`. Thanks anyway for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `self.classToUpdate` isn't nil while executing? 
Maybe you're not initializing that class anywhere?

Replace `update` method in `SubOtherClass` with this code:

```
- (void) update{
    if(!self.classToUpdate){
        NSLog(@"classToUpdate is nil");
    }

    [self.classToUpdate update:self];
}
```

And look on the console if 'classToUpdate is nil' text appears

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that the variable was `nil`. How do I make it NOT nil? When I add `self.classToUpdate = [ClassToUpdate new]` Xcode tells me "Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment". Any suggestions? How do I make a constructor?

Comment: `self.classToUpdate = [[ClassToUpdate alloc] init]`

Comment: I get the same warning... Am I missing something here? Do I need to add something in the `@property` declaration? I have `assign`.

Comment: when you're creating that variable? Before invoking `update` method?

Maybe it's released somewhere if it's on `assign` ? Switch to `retain` to be sure :)

Comment: It's retain now, and I don't get the error anymore, but the variable is still nil.

Comment: I've edited the answer (changed if condition) - check if 'classToUpdate is nil' isn't occuring.

It would be easier if you'll post full project so I could debug it

Answer (score 0):

In your drawrect method just include this line:-

```
        [super drawrect:rect]
```

So that it call super class drawrect method